# How to create recycler view in Compose Jetpack?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, android-compose-lazyfor

Is there any special way to create recyclerView in Compose Jetpack? Or it is the same as usual?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563183/9764941 -- your solution for dev.14

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update March 2021**: Starting from `1.0.0-beta01`

- [`LazyColumn`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazycolumn) for a vertical list
- [`LazyRow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazyrow) for a horizontal list

For example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LazyRowItemsDemo() {
    LazyRow {
        items((1..1000).toList()) {
            Text(text = "Item $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to reverse the `LazyColumnFor` like you can with `ScrollableColumn(        reverseScrollDirection = true)`?

Comment: full source code is available with an example  https://github.com/sureshmaidaragi1919/ComposeLazyColumn

Answer (score 10):

Examples from JetNews app have static data. It's worth to mention that according to the [recent Google presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsStyq4Lzxo) (see especially from 18:30), we should consider `ScrollingList`, which is intended for list with undefined number of elements (e.g. downloaded from the web), what was traditionally handled by `RecyclerView`. Then, it should look like this:

```
@Composable
fun NewsFeed(stories: List<StoryData>) {
  ScrollingList(stories) { story ->
    StoryWidget(story)
  }
}
```

or we can do similar thing with `LiveData` or RxJava `Observable`/`Flowable`:

```
@Composable
fun NewsFeed(stories: LiveData<List<StoryData>>) {
  ScrollingList(stories.observe()) { story ->
    StoryWidget(story)
  }
}
```

In such case, we are re-using `StoryWidget` (or any other widget of our choice) in the every step of the iteration with data emitted dynamically through the lambda expression.

Comment: From where is ```ScrollingList``` element? I'm trying use it and it can not be found for the IDE.

Comment: @LucasSousa You are right. `ScrollingList` is not element. I google it and found that `ScrollingList` is not available now. It will be available in the next release. So, we have to wait. (Found [here](https://blog.karumi.com/android-jetpack-compose-review/))

Answer (score 7):

In `jetnews` sample project for `list/recyclerview` they are using `VerticalScroller` with `Column` and using `forEach` to populate items below `@Composable` function is example

```
@Composable
private fun TabWithTopics(tabname: String, topics: List<String>) {
    VerticalScroller {
        Column {
            HeightSpacer(16.dp)
            topics.forEach { topic ->
                TopicItem(
                    getTopicKey(
                        tabname,
                        "- ",
                        topic
                    ), topic
                )
                TopicDivider()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For class and method check this link

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/master/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsScreen.kt

For more information you can download/clone `jetnews` sample from check here's link

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/master/JetNews

For latest Jetpack alpha release update the below:

```
@Composable
fun LazyRowItemsDemo() {
    LazyRowFor(items = (1..1000).toList()) {
        Text(text = "Item $it")
    }
}
```

1. [LazyColumnFor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyColumnFor(kotlin.collections.List,%20androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,%20androidx.compose.foundation.layout.InnerPadding,%20androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,%20kotlin.Function2)) for a vertical list
2. [LazyRowFor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyRowFor(kotlin.collections.List,%20androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,%20androidx.compose.foundation.layout.InnerPadding,%20androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,%20kotlin.Function2)) for a horizontal list

Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Yup. What about the recycling.

Answer (score 4):

Even further update for the new comers. As of **0.1.0-dev14**, `AdapterList` is deprecated in favor of `LazyColumnItems` and `LazyRowItems`.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** and current implementation at **dev06 Jetpack Compose** uses `AdapterList` and you could use the simple example included by [**Nurseyit Tursunkulov**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60595137/3743245) and I can share a more complex (real case scenario use):

- Your `List<Any>` must be "compose aware" and the current one available for that is `ModelList<Any>`
- You can create a model using `@Model` tag as those change the state, and your `@Compososable` function will be aware (using a `MutableList`)

**Example Code:**

```
fun addLogic(modelList: ModelList<MyModel>) {
  modelList.add(MyModel("Smith John", 10))
}

class MyModel(var name: String, var index: Int)

@Composable
fun RecycledList() { // Any name you want
  val modelList<MyModel> = modelListOf()
  var counter = 0

  addLogic(modelList)

  modelList.add(MyModel("John Doe", 99))

  MaterialTheme {
    Column {
      Container(height = 70.dp) {
         Align(alignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Button(onClick = { 
               modelList.add(MyModel("John Smith", counter++))
               // Any other logic you want
            }) {
               Text("ADD ITEM")
            }
         }
      }
      AdapterList(data = modelList) { item ->
         Center {
            Text("Hello ${item.name} - Index: ${item.index}")
         }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: AdapterList]

Answer (score 0):

[According to this article](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-adapterlist-in-jetpack-compose-1615865d8e7d) there is new version:

```
@Composable
fun <T> AdapterList(
 data: List<T>,
 modifier: Modifier = Modifier.None,
  itemCallback: @Composable() (T) -> Unit
)

@Composable
 fun Scrollable(
dragDirection: DragDirection,
scrollableState: ScrollableState,
onScrollStarted: (startedPosition: PxPosition) -> Unit = {},
onScrollStopped: (velocity: Float) -> Unit = {},
enabled: Boolean = true,
children: @Composable() () -> Unit
)

 AdapterList(
    data = (1..20).map { it }.toList()
) {
    if (it % 2 == 0) {
        Text("$it Even", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 40.sp, color = 
  Color.Gray))
    } else {
        Text(text = "$it Odd", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 70.sp))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that uses AdapterList for implementing recylcerview in compose

```
@Composable
fun Feeds(feeds:LiveData<List<Feed>>) {
    val mFeeds by feeds.observeAsState(emptyList())
    AdapterList(data = feeds){feed->
    FeedsItem(feed)
    }
}
```