# What is the Jetpack Compose equivalent of RecyclerView or ListView?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, how can I display a large list of data while laying out only the visible items, instead of composing and laying out every item on the initial layout pass?  This would be similar to `RecyclerView` and `ListView` in the `View` toolkit.

One could use a `for` loop to place all of the components inside of a `Column` in a `VerticalScroller`, but this would result in dropped frames and poor performance on larger numbers of items.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The equivalent component to `RecyclerView` or `ListView` in Jetpack Compose is [`LazyColumn`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazycolumn) for a vertical list and [`LazyRow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazyrow) for a horizontal list. These compose and lay out only the currently visible items.

You can use it by formatting your data as a list and passing it with a `@Composable` callback that emits the UI for a given item in the list.  For example:

```kotlin
val myData = listOf("Hello,", "world!")
LazyColumn {
    items(myData) { item ->
        Text(text = item)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val myData = listOf("Hello,", "world!")
LazyRow { 
    items(myData) { item ->
        Text(text = item)
    }
}
```

You can also specify individual items one at a time:

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    item {
        Text("Hello,")
    }
    item {
        Text("world!")
    }
}
```

```kotlin
LazyRow { 
    item {
        Text("Hello,")
    }
    item {
        Text("world!")
    }
}
```

There are also indexed variants, which provide the index in the collection in addition to the item itself:

```kotlin
val myData = listOf("Hello,", "world!")
LazyColumn {
    itemsIndexed(myData) { index, item ->
        Text(text = "Item #$index is $item")
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val myData = listOf("Hello,", "world!")
LazyRow { 
    itemsIndexed(myData) { index, item ->
        Text(text = "Item #$index is $item")
    }
}
```

These APIs were, in previous releases, known as `AdapterList`, `LazyColumnItems`/`LazyRowItems`, and `LazyColumnFor`/`LazyRowFor`.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering are there also any performance tips for using ```LazyColumnFor``` or ```LazyRowFor```? The information about this is really scarce right now on the web. It's really slow even in release mode, I tested with ```ConstraintLayout``` composable, which has a few images, some text and three buttons.

Comment: For more complex items, in RecyclerViews there is a differentiation between item-ID and item-Content, to identify content changes vs new items. Do you know how to achieve this differentiation in `LazyColumnFor`?

Comment: @SebasLG there is not currently such a differentiation.  To a large degree, it's unnecessary: if you use Compose state variables to hold the changing content, the child will recompose without being treated as a new item.

Comment: @RosenDimov have you had news? I am desperately trying to use LazyColumn but the perf is really really poor at the moment.

Comment: @sachadso, it seems that it's still too early and I guess more optimizations are to come. I last tried with ```alpha06```, and there was a slight boost, related to this issue that I logged (and a few other issues): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165028371 But still far from ```RecyclerView```'s behaviour.

Comment: what if we want a custom item adapter with listview?

Comment: checkout here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH5pTjz3STI

Answer (score 3):

> Update in dev.16

- [ScrollableColumn] for vertically scrolling list
- [ScrollableRow] for horizontally scrolling list

Check it's implementation from [ListCardViewTemplate](https://github.com/AliAzaz/PracticeComposeExamples/tree/ListCardViewTemplate)

---

You can get the same essence of `RecyclerView` or `ListView` in JetpackCompose using `AdapterList` that's renamed in dev.14 preview version.

- `[LazyColumnItems]` for vertically scrolling list
- `[LazyRowItems]` for horizontally scrolling list

Check what's documentation says:

> It was also moved into a `lazy` sub-package and split into two files. Plus I renamed params:
>
> 1. data -> items. this seems to be more meaningful then just raw
>    `data`
> 2. itemCallback -> itemContent. this is more meaningful and we
>    generally don't use word callback in the lambda names, especially for
>    composable lambdas

Check how to use it:

```
@Composable
fun <T> LazyColumnItems(
  items: List<T>,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  itemContent: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    LazyItems(items, modifier, itemContent, isVertical = true)
}
```

In .KT

```
LazyColumnItems(items = (0..50).toList()) { item ->
    cardViewImplementer(item)
 }
```

> From my perspective `LazyColumnItem` or `LazyRowItem` is not working properly if your item layout is complex because it's stuck the list as a comparison to `VerticalScroller` working fine in this scenario.

Comment: ```LazyRowItems``` and ```LazyColumnItems``` are deprecated now in favor of ```LazyRowFor``` and ```LazyColumnFor``` as per docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary.html?hl=pt-brhttps%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fstudio%2Frun%2Fmanaging-avds.html%3Fhl%3Dpt-br%22https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fmerchants%2Fanswer%2F188494%5C%22%22https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fmerchants%2Fanswer%2F188494%5C%22#lazyrowitems

Comment: yes in dev.16 they updated it. I've modified the answer

Comment: check implementation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH5pTjz3STI

Answer (score 0):

**LazyColumn** and **LazyRow** are euquavalant to Recycleview.

```
/*
*
*  LazyColumn produces a vertically scrolling list,
*  LazyRow produces a horizontally scrolling list.
*
* */

@Composable
fun addUserList(userDataList: List<User>) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {

        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(3.dp),
        ) {

            // header
            item {
                Text(text = "I'm header.")
            }

            // main content
            items(
                userDataList,
                itemContent = { user ->
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clickable {
                                context.showToast("you clicked ${user.name}")
                            },
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),


                        ) {
                        //Text(text = user.name)
                        UserView2(user = user)


                    }

                    // add diver color
                    Divider(color = Color.LightGray)

                },

                )


            // footer
            item {
                Text(
                    text = "I'm footer.",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//===============================//

Make sure you added glide compose dependency.

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:compose:1.0.0-alpha.1"
```

**Row View :**

// This is implementation for row view or equavalant to view in adapter which inflate for each row/record.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalGlideComposeApi::class)
@Composable
fun UserView2(user: User) {
    GlideImage(
        model = "https://datanapps.com/public/dnarestapi/user/renold1.png",
        contentDescription = "getString(R.id.picture_of_cat)",
        // shows an error ImageBitmap when the request failed.

        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.Cyan, shape = CircleShape)
            .padding(PaddingValues(1.dp))
            .clickable(enabled = true) { }
            .width(50.dp)
            .height(50.dp),
    )
    Text(text = user.name, color = Color.Blue)
    Text(text = user.email, color = Color.Cyan)
}
```

**Read More :**

Compose List >> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists

Glide compose >> https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/compose.html

Compose list Video >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ANt65eoNhQ&t=1s&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers

**Output :**

[image]