# What is the alternative to LinearLayout in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

What can I use instead of [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear) in Android Jetpack Compose? An example of how common LinearLayout features might be replaced by the new API would be nice to have.

Answer (score 15):

LinearLayout corresponds to [Row](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#row) and [Column](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#column) composables in Compose.

If you're going to display a large number of items take a look at [LazyRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary.html#lazyrow) and [LazyColumn](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary.html#lazycolumn) which display only visible items like [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview) does but you can use these as simple as Row and Column. See [What is the Jetpack Compose equivalent of RecyclerView or ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60765370/4858777) for an example.

Let's compare LinearLayout API to Row and Column:

---

**[android:orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/LinearLayout?hl=en#android:orientation)** (LinearLayout)
As you might guessed `<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>` is equivalent  to `Column {}` and `<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ...>` to `Row {}`

---

**[android:gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/LinearLayout?hl=en#android:gravity)** (LinearLayout)
There're `horizontalAlignment` & `verticalArrangement` arguments for [Column](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#column) and `verticalAlignment` & `horizontalArrangement` for [Row](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#row). For example:

```xml
<LinearLayout ...
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="end|center">
  ...
</LinearLayout>
```

is equivalent to

```kotlin
Column(
    ...
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) { ... }
```

---

**[android:layout_gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#android:layout_gravity)** (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
See Row's [align](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#align) and Column's [align](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#align) modifiers which override the container alignment if it's set. There're also more advanced modifiers like Row's [alignByBaseline](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#alignbybaseline), see the documentation for more details. For example:

```xml
<LinearLayout ...
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="end">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="first" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="second" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

is equal to

```kotlin
Column(
    ...
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
) {
    // this item is aligned to the end according to the column's alignment
    Text("first")
    // but this one is aligned to the start because it overrides the alignment
    Text("second", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start))
}
```

---

**[android:layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#android:layout_weight)** (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
See Row's [weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#weight) and Column's [weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#weight) modifiers. For example

```xml
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ...>
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="first" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="second" />
</LinearLayout>
```

is equal to

```kotlin
Row {
    Text("first", modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f))
    Text("second", modifier = Modifier.weight(2.0f))
}
```